# Blow the fuse if threshold exceeded

Tags: c#, datetime, timeout

While implementing the Retry & Breaker patterns I decided that the Breaker does more then it should so I extracted two responsibilities into their own classes. Here they are.

I stripped out the `Threshold` to be only data:

```
public class Threshold
{
    public Threshold(int count, TimeSpan interval, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        Count = count;
        Interval = interval;
        Timeout = timeout;
    }

    public int Count { get; }

    public TimeSpan Interval { get; }

    public TimeSpan Timeout { get; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Count = {Count} Interval = {Interval} Timeout = {Timeout}";
    }
}
```

The second responsibility is the object counting the events and checking if the threshold is exceeded. I call it `Fuse` and implemented it this way:

```
public class Fuse
{
    public Fuse(Threshold threshold)
    {
        Threshold = threshold;
    }

    // todo: add null check
    public IClock Clock { get; set; } = new SystemClock();

    public Threshold Threshold { get; }

    public int Count { get; private set; }

    public DateTime? Point { get; private set; }

    public bool Blown
    {
        get
        {
            return
                Clock.GetUtcNow() - Point <= Threshold.Interval &&
                Count >= Threshold.Count;
        }
    }

    public bool TimedOut
    {
        get { return (Clock.GetUtcNow() - Point) > Threshold.Timeout; }
    }   

    public Fuse Increase(int value)
    {
        if (TimedOut) { Reset(); }
        Count += value;
        Point = Clock.GetUtcNow();
        return this;
    }

    public Fuse Increase()
    {
        Increase(1);
        return this;
    }

    public Fuse Reset()
    {
        Count = 0;
        Point = null;
        return this;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Count = {Count} Point = \"{Point?.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}\" Blown = {Blown} TimedOut = {TimedOut}";
    }
}
```

To be able to better test it I created an abstraction for the `DateTime` and called it `IClock`:

```
public interface IClock
{
    DateTime GetNow();
    DateTime GetUtcNow();
}

public class SystemClock : IClock
{
    public DateTime GetNow() => DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime GetUtcNow() => DateTime.UtcNow;
}

public class TestClock : IClock
{
    public DateTime Now { get; set; }
    public DateTime UtcNow { get; set; }
    public DateTime GetNow() => Now;
    public DateTime GetUtcNow() => UtcNow;
}
```

Without the breaker the two new modules are now easier to test:

```
var threshold = new Threshold(count: 3, interval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
var fuse = new Fuse(threshold) { Clock = new TestClock { UtcNow = new DateTime(2016, 11, 12, 9, 0, 0) } };
fuse.Increase(2).ToString().Dump();
fuse.Increase().ToString().Dump();
(fuse.Clock as TestClock).UtcNow = new DateTime(2016, 11, 12, 9, 0, 0).AddSeconds(20);
fuse.ToString().Dump();
fuse.Increase().ToString().Dump();
```

Output:

```
Count = 2 Point = "11/12/2016 09:00:00" Blown = False TimedOut = False
Count = 3 Point = "11/12/2016 09:00:00" Blown = True TimedOut = False
Count = 3 Point = "11/12/2016 09:00:00" Blown = False TimedOut = True
Count = 1 Point = "11/12/2016 09:00:20" Blown = False TimedOut = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interface `Iclock` exposes methods `GetNow` and `GetUtcNow`.
Your `TestClock` class implements it, but because you also want to be able to modify the values you end up by implementing the properties `Now` and `UtcNow`.

In my opinion would be a better alternative that `IClock` would expose a read-only properties,
and that your class would expose the public setter as well:

```
public interface IClock
{
    DateTime Now{ get; }
    DateTime UtcNow{ get; }
}

public class TestClock : IClock
{
    public DateTime Now { get; set; }
    public DateTime UtcNow { get; set; }
}
```

Your `Increase` method in `Fuse` class is hard to get grasp on.

So... I migth be wrong but you do not want to keep track of the current time when `Increase` method is called.
What this means is that this line `Point = Clock.GetUtcNow();` would become

```
Point = Point ?? Clock.GetUtcNow();
```

Furthermore I would consider to move this to some other method.
It could be a wise choice to move it to the constructor, however if you want to have a better control about exactly which tim ite is related to you could have a start method.

```
public Fuse Start(){
    //if you want to you can check if Point is null and throw an exception if it's not
    Point = Clock.GetUtcNow();
}
```

It also seems that your `Increase` method sometimes decides to do his trick and call `Reset` method.
If I were a consumer of **any** API I would never guess that a method called `Increase` would reset something.

In my opinion one simple thing you can do it have a `boolean` flag that would decide if `Reset` should be called "automatically".

Obviously this change would be accompanied by a slightly better named method. 
Unfortunately nothing better than `ShortenFuse` comes to mind.

```
public class Fuse
{
    public Fuse(Threshold threshold)
    {
        Threshold = threshold;
        AutoReset = true;
    }

    public bool AutoReset{ get; set; }

    public Fuse ShortenFuse(int value)
    {
        if (TimedOut && AutoReset) { Reset(); }
        Count += value;
        return this;
    }
    //...
}
```

One more thing. In your "tests" you do this:

```
(fuse.Clock as TestClock).UtcNow = new DateTime(2016, 11, 12, 9, 0, 0).AddSeconds(20);
```

Wouldn't it be much better to put the seconds on the constructor?

Comment: I agree about most points and I have I have to defend one solution. I've read a book about best practices lately where the creators of the .NET admit themselves that the `DateTime.[Utc]Now` should have been methods `Get[Utc]Now` because they return a new value each time and not just _some_ data. You're right about the other points, especially about the unnecessary `Point` reset - I wasn't aware of this bug.

Comment: About the `Increase` method. I had a really hard time to come up with a name for it. Now after a while I have one more idea - perhaps `Measure` would be better. Other ideas I had were `Count`, `Track`, `Register`.

Comment: I didn't use the construtor for the `TestClock` because it was a copy/pase and somehow I didn't realize there might be another parameter :-o

Comment: Oh, and thanks to your review I have one more idea ;-D I make the `Timeout` optional (another constructor). If specified the `Fuse` will support `AutoRest` otherwise not.

Comment: @t3chb0t (About your first comment). Seems a reasonable reason. However if you have a reason to implement in that way you should prefer to implement the interface `IClock` explicitly so users of `TestClock` don't see both `GetNow` and `Now`

Comment: Ok, one more idea for the `Incease`. I've been just reading wiki about fuses and they write _The fuse is arranged in series to carry all the current **passing** through the protected circuit._ I think the names `PassOne()` and `Pass(int)` should be perfect.

Comment: @t3chb0t LGTM :p